# How to use plantuml plugin in vs 2019

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, plantuml

I'm trying to copy puml files from to C#,

please help me to use plantuml plugin in vs creat puml file in vs2019.

[image]

Cannot find tutorial about VS 2019.
[Description by plugin author](https://github.com/kiebor/PlantUml-Language-Service)

[image]

Comment: There is other user report the similar issue:

[Preview not working anymore](https://github.com/kiebor/PlantUml-Language-Service/issues/14)

The extension seems stop update. You may need to contact the owner of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is other user report the similar issue:

[Preview not working anymore](https://github.com/kiebor/PlantUml-Language-Service/issues/14)

The extension seems stop update. You may need to contact the owner of the extension.